# Hyphenation is constantly wrong in English

Tags: polyglossia

The title says pretty much everything.
Waveguide becomes wav-eguide
Vertically becomes vertic-ally
Important becomes import-ant
Here are my modules:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{gensymb}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[2]{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \begin{otherlanguage*}{#1}\hyphenation{#2}\end{otherlanguage*}%
  }%
}

\sethyphenation{english}{wave-guide}
```

There's also a command I'm using to minimize this problem, as I thought it was just related to waveguide (maybe a word not in the dictionary), but as it appears to happen every time, I can't overwrite every single word like this.

(it was the same with babel and not polyglossia)

Comment: please edit your example so that it demonstrates the problem. If I comment out `\sethyphenation{english}{wave-guide}` and add `\showhyphens{waveguide}` then the system reports `\TU/lmr/m/n/10.95 wave-guide` showing that the hyphenation is not, as you report, wav-eguide. If you do get that make an example, and show the log file.

Comment: I get `wave-guide im-port-ant ver-tic-ally`, which look right.

Comment: You're actually right, it now seems to be working correctly. I don't know where the first error came from (if you remove polyglossia you will see it hypenated wrong, but that's ok), maybe also from the fact that since english is not my mother tongue, those other hypenations (important, vertically...) sounded very wrong to me.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time

Comment: You really do **not** want to use `eurosym` with `fontspec`, as you're currently doing.